# jquery find - if class element ".myclass" is within body, but outside other element

Tags: jquery, find

Since I've got more than one correct answer, I'm answering

Thanks for your help

this was the sollution here

$('body').children('.class_to_find');

Thanks

Sorry for bad formating of example, this markdown system in not good.

I may have more than 1 element with the same class in my document, but I need to just find those who are outside any element but body, example

```
<body>
    <div class="class_to_find">my div</div>
    <div class="testing">
       <div class="class_to_find">my other div</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I just want to catch 'my div', but of course this

```
$('body').find('.class_to_find');
```

does catch all, since they're all within body, what should I do?

Comment: what do you mean when you say outside of body? in your example both elements are inside of the body tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the direct parent-child selector:

```
$('body > .class_to_find')....
```

or `.children()`, which only searches direct descendents:

```
$('body').children('.class_to_find')...
```

Comment: thanks, everybody solved this, what do I do? I can't put all as correct replyers

Comment: @Pluda normal procedure is to 'accept' the answer that was most complete ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method as it searches only within immediate children.

Try:

```
$('body').children('.class_to_find');
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it sounds like this would work :

```
$('body').children('.class_to_find');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('body>div.class_to_find');
```